# How to make a "partially materialized" view in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql-view, materialized-views

I have a data mart in Oracle RDBMS that has to provide access to a list of entries. Each row in `ENTRY` will have `ENTRY_ID (PK)`, `ENTRY_DATE` and many additional attributes. The problem is that on one hand, computing each row takes time, since there are multiple joins on large tables that have to be carried out and many attributes are transformed using functions; on the other hand, storing all entries in the mart takes too much space.

However, I know that 99% of the entries selected from the mart have `ENTRY_DATE` within one year from today. I could split the list of entries into `RECENT_ENTRIES`, which would contain only entries from the last 365 days, and `OLD_ENTRIES`, which would actually be a view. But that would require everyone consuming this data to check both.

Is there a way to aggregate `RECENT_ENTRIES` and `OLD_ENTRIES` into a single view that ensures that as long as you filter the results by `ENTRY_DATE` or access the data using `ENTRY_ID`, it won't access `OLD_ENTRIES` unless it's necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view that does a `UNION ALL` between subqueries on `RECENT_ENTRIES` and `OLD_ENTRIES`.

Put predicates on the subqueries that explicitly state the date ranges they support - that way those parts of the execution plan may be skipped by the optimiser. e.g.

```
create view all_entries as
select * from recent_entries where entry_date >= sysdate-365
union all
select * from old_entries where entry_date < sysdate - 365;
```